# PKI subordinate CA - TLS certificate

Tags: ssl, pki, ca

If I have a root CA for ".com" domain and I release a subCA certificate with "Name constrain" "example.com" or ".example.com", is it the same?

When I have the subCA certificate for the domain "example.com" could I release "testexample.com" certificate and they are still valid?

Thank you.